# How should I go about making a List method return a String value?

Tags: java

Not sure how else to word it. Basically I have a method that returns a List, but if the list is empty then I want a String returned. What is the best way of doing this?

```
if(list.isEmpty()){
    return "index";
    }else{
    return list;
    }
```

Comment: You can't return two different types. You could return a list with just a single element in it. Would that work?

Comment: Well, you can't do it.  A method can't return two different types.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952856/how-to-write-java-function-that-returns-values-of-multiple-data-types

Comment: What's your reasoning for returning the String?   (Or stated a different way, what's the name of the method that includes this code?)

Comment: The reason is to redirect to an error page (jsf)

Answer (score 2):

One of the main Java advantages is that it is strongly typed language, and you should avoid attempts to break it (if this is problem for you, use weakly typed languages like JavaScript, where type can be changed at runtime easily).

If you need a `String` to be returned, wrap it with immutable list of 1 element:

```
return list.isEmpty() ? Arrays.asList("index") : list;
```

Another way is to return the most general type: `Object`, but I see it absolutely senseless.

Answer (score 0):

First, the only way to return a `List` or a `String` is to return an `Object`.  But that forces the caller to determine the actual type of the returned object.

What is the purpose of returning a `String` here?  It looks like it's to inform the caller of an error.  If so, then the proper procedure here is to throw an exception.  Instead of returning `"index"`, throw some kind of exception, either built-in or of a type you create.  Then you can just have the method's return type be `List` (or `List<SomeDataType>`).

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but it really needs to be emphasized that you throw an exception if there's *an error*.  Not to tell the caller some legitimate state has occurred.  In this case, if the list *can* be empty, then I would vote against using an exception.  If it cannot, then an exception would be appropriate.