# Java, what if I want to return different types from function?

Tags: java

```
public WHATTOWRITEHERE test()
{
    try
    {
        transaction.begin();
        code which may trigger exception
        transaction.commit();
        return true;
    }
    catch (javax.script.ScriptException ex)
    {
        transaction.rollback();
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

the code above intend to do something, if its OK then return `true` if not (error happened), this error message `string` should be returned. It do possible with Php but not with Java

EDIT: expection cant go outside, it has to be handled right here.

Comment: Just return a bool or throw an exception when smth goes wrong. Leave the exception handling to the caller.

Comment: It's not possible in Java. Let the exception fall through instead.

Comment: Since you don't want exception to go outside, here's what you can do. Return "true" as a string if all goes well. And if some error occurs then return the error message. In the method signature, make the return type String. This is basically a bad design.

Comment: This is certainly a duplicate. Take a look at [How to write Java function that returns values of multiple data types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952856/how-to-write-java-function-that-returns-values-of-multiple-data-types). I certainly expect there are others.

Comment: Since it is a requirement that the `ScriptException` does not escape outside your method: could some other exception be thrown after rollback to indicate a failure? One standard scheme would be to wrap the original exception in a new exception of a type that the caller can be expected to deal with.

Comment: You *really really* should use **`throw ex;`** instead of `return ex.getMessage();`

Comment: @tkausl Sure it is possible in Java: use `Object`. See my answer below for how to emulate PHP style (and why it is bad) as well as how to *safely* do this with Java 7 try-with-resources and exceptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't return multiple types but you can redesign so you don't have to. Some possibilities:

1. Don't return an error message. Throw or rethrow an exception instead and let the caller handle it.
2. Create some class that can encapsulate a success and error state and all related info, return an instance of that.

I recommend option 1. You're already handling an exception, you can see its use for it error handling. No reason to stop it in its tracks there, handle any local cleanup then keep it going up to the caller.

---

Some hastily constructed examples now that I'm back at a keyboard, intended only to illustrate concepts, not to be exhaustive or necessarily used verbatim:

Cleanup then rethrow:

```
public boolean test () throws javax.script.ScriptException {
    try {
        transaction.begin();
        ...
        transaction.commit();
        return true;
    } catch (javax.script.ScriptException ex) {
        transaction.rollback();
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Clean up then rethrow a different exception type if needed:

```
public boolean test () throws MyGreatException {
    try {
        transaction.begin();
        ...
        transaction.commit();
        return true;
    } catch (javax.script.ScriptException ex) {
        transaction.rollback();
        throw new MyGreatException(ex);
    }
}
```

Return an object that provides status information (this is just a quick example of the general idea):

```
public class TransactionResult {

    private final boolean failed;
    private final String reason;

    /** Construct a result that represents a successful transaction. */
    public TransactionResult () { 
        failed = false; 
        reason = null;
    }

    /** Construct a result that represents a failed transaction with a reason. */
    public TransactionResult (String failedReason) {
        failed = true;
        reason = failedReason;
    }

    public boolean isFailed () {
        return failed;
    }

    public String getReason () {
        return reason;
    }

}
```

And then:

```
public TransactionResult test () {
    TransactionResult result;
    try {
        transaction.begin();
        ...
        transaction.commit();
        result = new TransactionResult();
    } catch (javax.script.ScriptException ex) {
        transaction.rollback();
        result = new TransactionResult(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Etc.

Comment: I diddnt metion, but its a transaction-handling method, so no expectation can go outside

Comment: @john Then you have to choose option 2 or some variation of it. What do you *do* exactly with the returned value? That may help narrow down your options. I'm on my phone otherwise I'd type up a good option 2 example, sorry.

Comment: the caller checks its value, it its not true, then we alert the exception message.

Comment: @JohnSmith The exception can and should be thrown outside the method. You can catch it inside the method, perform the `rollback()` and then *rethrow* the exception to indicate that the operation failed (and was rolled back). Any other approach is just bad design.

Comment: ^ @JohnSmith What Kayaman said, with the note that sometimes questionable design is forgivable in little one-off programs, or when you're faced with somebody else's poor constraints that you have to work around, but not if you are in a moderately serious development environment and have full control over the design choices you make. :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't return anything. Just [re-throw the original exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097527/rethrowing-exceptions-in-java-without-losing-the-stack-trace) after you roll-back.

```
public void test()
{
    try
    {
        transaction.begin();
        code which may trigger exception
        transaction.commit();
    }
    catch (javax.script.ScriptException ex)
    {
        transaction.rollback();
        throw ex;     // re-throw the original exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you insist, you can return `Object`. In that case, true will be autoboxed to `Boolean.TRUE`. It’s certainly not recommended, and it will give the caller some extra trouble figuring out whether the returned object is a `String` or a `Boolean`. To make matters worse, the caller has no guarantee that return types are limited to the mentioned two, but should also take into account that it could be yet another class.

Better options depend on the situation, so I probably cannot tell you what’s best. A couple of ideas spring to mind, but please don’t use uncritically: (1) Return `String`, and return `null` instead of true on success. (2) Design your own return class; for instance, it may hold both a boolean and a message string.

Answer (score 2):

UGLY Workaround but if you really want to do this you can always define a Helper class which wraps status and Error Message, **but I would prefer @JsonC's approach.**

```
// Helper class 
class Pair<First,Second>{
    private First first;
    private Second second;
    Pair(First first,Second second){ 
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second; 
    } 
    public First getFirst(){ return this.first; } 
    public First getSecond(){ return this.second; }
}

// Function returning two types
public Pair<boolean,String> returnSomething(){
    try {
       return new Pair<boolean,String>(true,null);
    }catch(Exception e){
       return new Pair<boolean,String>(false,e.getMessage());
    }
}

// Calling this method would look like this
Pair<String,boolean> result = returnSomething();

// Retrieve status 
boolean status = result.getFirst();

// Retrieve error message (This is null if an exception was caught!)

String errorMessage = result.getSecond();
```

Comment: Ugly for the win (but [the first part of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39182267/616460)'s got you beat for ugly, ha)! +1

Comment: Yeah it was posted while I was struggling with indentation on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

> Exceptions can't go outside, it has to be handled here.

I must say this restriction can only make the interface more difficult to use. Assume you want to return something for the caller to check whether an exception happened in this method, while the caller can ignore the returned value no matter what. So I guess you want to give the caller some flexibility: that he/she doesn't need to bother with the final result if possible. But with the exception approach the caller can still do that, with empty (not recommended) catch clauses.

Exception is the best approach here. Unless "outside" is an environment where exceptions are not supported. Then you have no choice but to come up with something like `Try` in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your case, ***exceptions* should probably be *used*, not hidden**. It's not a *result* but an error. Learn how to do exception handling in transactions!
2. Functional programming fanboys will advocate a Monad-like structure, as you can find in the `Optional<T>` API of Java 8.

   I.e. you could return `Optional<String>` and leave it unset on success (if you do not have a `return false` and a `return true`).
3. For clarity it would be better to build something like this instead with custom classes:

   ```
   interface Result {}
   class BooleanResult implements Result {
     boolean result;
     public boolean getResult() { return result; }
   }
   class ErrorResult implements Result {
     Exception cause;
     public Exception getCause() { return cause; }
   }
   ```
4. You could emulate `Optional` with `null` values (if you have only one boolean result). On success, return `null`. Non-null values indicate errors.

   ```
   String perform() { 
     try{
       ...
       return null; // No error
     } except(Exception e) { // bad code style
       return e.getMessage(); // Pray this is never null
     }
   }

   String err = perform();
   if (err != null) { throw up; }
   ```

   Similar APIs are fairly common in old C libraries. Any return value except 0 is an error code. On success, the results are written to a pointer provided at the method call.
5. You could use `Object`.

   ```
   public Object perform() {...}

   Object o = perform();
   if (o instanceof Boolean) { ...
   ```

   This is 1980s programming style. **This is what PHP does**, so it actually *is* possible in Java! It's just *bad* because it is no lpnger type safe. This is the worst choice.

I suugest your try 1., 3., 2., 4., 5. in this preference. Or better, only consider the options 1 and 3 at all.

As for option 1. you *really* should learn how to use try-with-resources. Your transaction *is* a resource.

When done right, your code will look like this:

```
try(Transaction a = connection.newTransaction()) {
  doSomethingThatMayFail(a);
  a.commit();
} // No except here, let try handle this properly
```

Java will call `a.close()` *even* if an exception occurs. Then it will throw the exception upwards. Sour transaction class should have code like this to take care of the rollback:

```
public void close() {
  if (!committed) rollback();
}
```

This is the most elegant *and* shortest *and* safe-to-use approach, as Java ensures `close()` is called. **Throw the Exception**, then properly handle it. The code snipped you showed above is an anti-pattern, and known to be very error prone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 you could return an `Optional<String>`. Then if the code succeeds you return an empty Optional and if there is a failure you return an optional wrapping the failure message.